# Plugin/bookmarklet for css retina images test

Tags: css, plugins, retina-display, bookmarklet

Does anyone know if there is any plugin or bookmarklet to test retina images in css on the regular desktop? I mean it should do something like getting retina css image related queries from all css of the page and applied (add) them to this page even if it's not a retina.

I tried googling for it, but found nothing.

P.S. I do it manually now: commenting retina media queries in my css files, but working with such plugin would be more convenient.

Comment: plugin/bookmarklet generally involve JavaScript, is that what you're looking for?  (might add JavaScript tag if so).  Cursory search for retina plugin yields some jQuery plugins: [retinise](https://github.com/dahliacreative/retinise.js) and [jQuery Retina Plugin](http://www.tylercraft.com/projects/jquery-retina-plugin/)

Comment: This is not I'm looking for. I mean a plugin that does smth like that: it gets all page styles, parses it and looks for retina media queries, extracts all styles from there and appends in to the page.